# Sitecore: hiding fields in content editor?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I'm part of a team building a website in Sitecore. We've added a template field whose value we want to hide from content editors.

(the field contains extra CSS classes for a page so we can target styles at specific pages. Not best-practice - we should put it in code - but it has its advantages when the site is in production.)

Any way to do hide specific fields in the Sitecore content editor?

Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should restrict `Field Read` access to the field (so not `Read` access)

[image]

Comment: You could also check the "hidden" field on the field under the template. But editors can see it if they got "show hidden" on - depends on how much you want to hide the field

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it'll solve the problem - and in a nice way, I am guessing we can even use Sitecore's security to show the field to members of specific group(s). Fantastic!

Comment: @dunston interestingly, I found the "hidden" checkbox didn't do that - it hides the _template field_ item, rather than hiding the value of that field when editing items who are instances of the template. If you look at that checkbox you'll see it's labelled "hidden items", so the two are related but they aren't when I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Ruud's got the ticket, I think. Just to tack a little bit on to his answer, and because I wasn't sure how to do this myself the first time I worked w/ field-level security, select the Columns button in the toolbar to show the Field Read & Field Write options in the Security Editor.

[image: Sitecore security toolbar w/ Columns highlighted]

[image: Sitecore security column dialog]

Answer (score 1):

You could restrict read-access to the field, for the usergroup.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answers already given, you should probably add your settings as a rendering parameter, which will allow you to target renderings/controls more specifically rather than entire "pages", and allow you to set different classes on different components of the page.

[Introduction to Sitecore Parameter Templates: Sitecore client configuration deep dive](http://blog.nonlinearcreations.com/2011/12/introduction-to-sitecore-parameter-templates-sitecore-client-configuration-deep-dive/)

[Introduction to Sitecore Parameter Templates: Making sublayout configuration more intuitive](http://blog.nonlinearcreations.com/2011/12/introduction-to-parameter-templates-making-sublayout-configuration-more-intuitive/)

Use the [Sublayout Parameter Helper](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sub_Layout_Parameter_Helper.aspx) to get the values in your code behind.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea - cheers, I'll look into doing that as well.